# Respuesta de un echo en un div ID

Tags: php, html, mysql, login

Buenas estoy haciendo un inicio de sesión y necesitaria que el echo que me responde que no existe ese usuario o contraseña me lo muestre en un div dentro del formulario en lugar de un echo.

`resupuesta.php`

```
   <?php
    require('conexion/conexion.php');
    session_start();
    // If form submitted, insert values into the database.
    if($_POST["funcion"]=="FUNCION"){
    // removes backslashes
      $username = stripslashes($_REQUEST['username']);
      //escapes special characters in a string
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username);
      $password = stripslashes($_REQUEST['password']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$password);
    //Checking is user existing in the database or not
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Username='$username'";
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysql_error());
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        echo "1";
        //header("Location: mi-cuenta.php");
      }else{
        ?>
        <div class='form'> 
             <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
             <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a>
        </div>
        <?
   }
 exit();
 }
?>
```

AJAX

```
<script>
    var post=$.post('respuesta.php',{
        funcion:'FUNCION'
    },function(msg){
        if(msg=="1"){
            window.lcoation="index.php";
        }else{
            $("#respuesta").append(msg);
            //alert(msg);
        }
    });
</script>
```

Esto el HTML con el FORM

```
<div class="wrap-user">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrap-user__in">
      <aside class="wrap-user__aside">
      <header class="wrap-user__header wrap-user__header--inline-small">
         <a href="#" class="wrap-user__header__link">o BIEN CREATE AUNA CUENTA</a>
         <h1 class="wrap-user__header__title h5user2">Inicia Sesión</h1>
      </header>
         <p class="puser2">En Depildiodo protegemos todos los datos de forma segura (HTTP/SSL)</p>
      </aside>
      <main class="wrap-user__content">
        <div class="form">
        <h5 class="h5user">INICIA SESIÓN CON TU CUENTA</h5>
        <form action="" method="post" name="login">
            <label style="color: #737373;font-weight: 100;">EMAIL</label>
            <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 28px;">
             <input type="text" class=" my-form-control" name="username" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" required />
            </div>

            <label style="color: #737373;font-weight: 100;">CONTRASEÑA</label>
            <div class="form-group">
             <input type="password" class=" my-form-control" name="password" placeholder="minimo 4 cararcteres" required />
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5%; padding: 0px;">
              <input name="chec" class="chzxc" type="checkbox" id="chec" onChange="comprobar(this);"/>
            <label class="aceptatm">He leído y acepto la <a href="aviso_legal.php">Términos y Condiciones</a></label>
            </div>

           **<div id="respuesta">RESPUESTA</DIV>**

            <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Iniciar Sesión" disabled />
                        </form>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

Fin del php

```
<?php } ?>  **Esta llave si estando en funcionamineto???**
```

Comment: Haz probado con AJAX?

Comment: No, la verdad que lo he utilizado alguna vez para la actualización de registros, pero aun no logro entender bien su funcionamiento

Comment: Imagina que es un intermediario que permite comunicar de forma asíncrona entre tu servidor y tu cliente, puede hacer una función que envié y una que reciba. Dame unos minutos y te paso un ejemplo

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda @Ruben Hernandez

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<div class="wrap-user">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="wrap-user__in">
            <aside class="wrap-user__aside">
                <header class="wrap-user__header wrap-user__header--inline-small">
                    <a href="#" class="wrap-user__header__link">o BIEN CREATE AUNA CUENTA</a>
                    <h1 class="wrap-user__header__title h5user2">Inicia Sesión</h1>
                </header>
                <p class="puser2">En Depildiodo protegemos todos los datos de forma segura (HTTP/SSL)</p>
            </aside>
            <main class="wrap-user__content">
                <div class="form">
                    <h5 class="h5user">INICIA SESIÓN CON TU CUENTA</h5>
                    <form name="login">
                        <label style="color: #737373;font-weight: 100;">EMAIL</label>
                        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom: 28px;">
                            <input type="text" class=" my-form-control" id="username" name="username" placeholder="nombre@ejemplo.com" required />
                        </div>

                        <label style="color: #737373;font-weight: 100;">CONTRASEÑA</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="password" id="password" class=" my-form-control" name="password" placeholder="minimo 4 cararcteres" required />
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="text-align: left; margin-top: 5%; padding: 0px;">
                            <input name="chec" class="chzxc" type="checkbox" id="chec" onChange="comprobar(this);"/>
                            <label class="aceptatm">He leído y acepto la <a href="aviso_legal.php">Términos y Condiciones</a></label>
                        </div>

                        <div id="respuesta">RESPUESTA</div>

                        <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" class="btnLogin" value="Iniciar Sesión" disabled />
                    </form>
                </div>
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var post=$.post('respuesta.php',{
            funcion:'FUNCION',
            username:$("#username").val(),
            password:$("#password").val(),
        },function(msg){
            if(msg=="1"){
                window.location="index.php";
            }else{
                $("#respuesta").html(msg);
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

respuesta.php

```
<?php
require('conexion/conexion.php');
@session_start();

if($_POST["funcion"]=="FUNCION"){
      $username = stripslashes($_POST['username']);
      $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$username);
      $password = stripslashes($_POST['password']);
      $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$password);
      $query = "SELECT * FROM Usuarios WHERE Username='$username'";
      $result = mysqli_query($mysqli,$query) or die(mysql_error());
      $rows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
      if($rows==1){
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;
        $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
        echo "1";
        //header("Location: mi-cuenta.php");
      }else{
        ?>
        <div class='form'> 
             <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
             <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a>
        </div>
        <?php
   }
 exit();
}
?>
```

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda, pero ves lo que no tengo claro nunca que es lo que iria en respuesta php? que seria el codigo php que tengo? si es así, que tendria que poner en el echo del php?

Comment: En la respuesta del AJAX la variable "msg" puede contener html así que en la función PHP puedes poner toda tu función de validación en PHP. Modifico mi respuesta para que veas este caso

Comment: Vale vale, algo lo voy entendiendo, pero si paso todo el php a respuesta.php, como hago una cosa. Si te das cuenta en el código de arriba el php esta partido y entre medias html y luego cerramos la llave del php

Comment: Mira @Miguel en la parte de abajo de la respuesta te puse un ejempo :)

Comment: Me devuelve la página en blanco, voy a editar mi pregunta y ves como lo he hecho

Comment: Pregunta editada, chequea si puedes, gracias!

Comment: Listo prueba ahora y me comentas :)

Comment: me devuelve este error: login.php:36 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined y cuando inicia sale otro y no me deja tampoco iniciar

Comment: Si tienes que agregar antes del <script></script> la llamada a JQuery, puedes usar la que te puse en el JS de la respuesta

Comment: Vale puse el script abajo del todo, ya que tengo la libreria 2.1.3. Pero ahora me sale otro error.      jquery.js:8625 POST http://localhost:8888/depildiodo/respuesta.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Aca ya es error de tu PHP, revisa las rutas de los require

Comment: jejjeje era por un llave de php que estaba así la abertura <? y he tenido que ponerla así <?php. Muchas gracias @Ruben Hernandez

Comment: Genial @Miguel mucho exito!!!

Comment: Espera :( pero ahora no reconoce los usuarios que si estan correctos!

Comment: MMM puede ser que las variables tendriamos que recibirlas con $_POST, edito de nuevo la respuesta

Comment: Listo @Miguel prueba con los cambios es la respuesta, ahí envió y recibo los datos por POST en el AJAX

Comment: Listo @Ruber Hernandez, solo cambia esta letra en el AJAX window.lcoation="index.php";  -- Tiene que poner location, me estaba volviendo loco ajajaj, muchisimas gracias!

Comment: Genial @Miguel pura vida!!!

Answer (score 1):

Si no quieres usar ajax simplemente declara una variable:

```
$respuesta = "<div class='form'> 
     <h3>Username/password is incorrect.</h3>
     <br/>Click here to <a href='login.php'>Login</a></div>";
```

Y luego muestrala

```
<div id="respuesta"><?php echo $respuesta ?></div>
```

Comment: Hola gracias por la respuesta, me gusta tu idea y la quiero aprender, pero voy a aprender primero la forma del ajax